# Set state from a Function's var return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setState GenPass function's var pass to passString state; however, it somehow doesn't work. Console log showing the expected passString, but the passString state somehow didn't change, and couldn't be shown by the html part.

```
class GeneratePassString extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      passString: null,
      formErrors: {
      passString: ""
      }
    };
  }
  
  GenPassFunction() {
    var pass ="";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()";
  
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      pass += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      this.setState({passString: this.pass})
      console.log(pass);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='genPassString'>
        <div className='formGenPassString'>
          <h1>{this.state.passString}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="genButton">
          <button onClick={() => this.GenPassFunction()}>Generate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GeneratePassString;
```

Comment: `{passString: this.pass}` should be `{passString: pass}` since you want to use the local `pass` variable (`this.pass` doesn't exist anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much!